# Laravel 5.2 Pagination docs warning? what does it mean exactly

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

Laravel 5.2 docs states this:

> Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a `groupBy` statement
>   cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a
>   `groupBy` with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query
>   the database and create a paginator manually.

But I have successfully used `Paginate()` on many "multiple left joined group by having" queries on large databases, both in SQLSRV and MySQL without any problems. So what exactly does this "cannot be executed efficiently" mean exactly? Will my output be wrong at random occasions or is it just "slow" ?